Computing Expectations in Fisher Information Matrix for Gaussian Mixture Models
Consider a Gaussian Mixture Model (GMM) with $K$ components:
$p(x) = \sum_{k=1}^K \pi_k \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_k, \Sigma_k)$
where $\pi_k$ are mixing coefficients, $\mu_k$ are mean vectors, and $\Sigma_k$ are covariance matrices.
The responsibilities $\gamma_k(x)$ are defined as:
$\gamma_k(x) = \frac{\pi_k \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_k, \Sigma_k)}{\sum_{j=1}^K \pi_j \mathcal{N}(x; \mu_j, \Sigma_j)}$
In computing the Fisher Information Matrix (FIM) for this GMM, I encounter two types of expectations:

$\mathbb{E}[\gamma_k(x)\gamma_l(x)]$

$\mathbb{E}[\gamma_k(x)\gamma_l(x)f(x)]$, where $f(x)$ could be expressions like $(x-\mu_k)^T\Sigma_k^{-1}(x-\mu_k)$


Questions:

Are there more precise expressions or methods to compute $\mathbb{E}[\gamma_k(x)\gamma_l(x)]$, especially when components are not well-separated?

How can I approach computing $\mathbb{E}[\gamma_k(x)\gamma_l(x)f(x)]$? Are there analytical methods or standard approximations for such terms?

Are there established techniques in the literature for handling these types of expectations in the context of FIM for GMMs?


Any insights, references, or solution strategies would be greatly appreciated.
